# Conda fails to solve environment while installing new package

Tags: linux, anaconda

My conda version is 4.7.12 in linux mint 18.3. I was installing the package pygame using "conda install -c cogsci pygame". It was showing some sort of incompatibility messages, which I did not read due to lack of time. I just aborted using "ctrl+c". After that I am not able to install any package through conda, it fails to solve environment. The message is as follows:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
>
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>
> Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
>
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
>
> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Any suggestion how to fix this issue?